# sort-by on a lazy sequence of hash-maps in clojure

Tags: clojure, hashmap, quicksort, lazy-sequences

I need to take 20 results from a lazy sequence of millions of hash-maps but for the 20 to be based on sorting on various values within the hashmaps.

For example:

```
(def population [{:id 85187153851 :name "anna" :created #inst "2012-10-23T20:36:25.626-00:00" :rank 77336}
         {:id 12595145186 :name "bob" :created #inst "2011-02-03T20:36:25.626-00:00" :rank 983666}
         {:id 98751563911 :name "cartmen" :created #inst "2007-01-13T20:36:25.626-00:00" :rank 112311}
         ...
         {:id 91514417715 :name "zaphod" :created #inst "2015-02-03T20:36:25.626-00:00" :rank 9866}]
```

In normal circumstances a simple `sort-by` would get the job done:

```
(sort-by :id population)
(sort-by :name population)
(sort-by :created population)
(sort-by :rank population)
```

But I need to do this across millions of records as fast as possible and want to do it lazily rather than having to realize the entire data set.

I looked around a lot and found a number of implementations of algorithms that work really well for sorting a sequence of values (mostly numeric) but none for a lazy sequence of hash-maps in the way I need.

Speed & efficiency being of prime importance, the best I have found has been the quicksort example from the [*Joy Of Clojure*](http://joyofclojure.com/) book (Chapter 6.4) which does just enough work to return the required result.

```
(ns joy.q)

(defn sort-parts
  "Lazy, tail-recursive, incremental quicksort.  Works against
   and creates partitions based on the pivot, defined as 'work'."
  [work]
  (lazy-seq
   (loop [[part & parts] work]
     (if-let [[pivot & xs] (seq part)]
       (let [smaller? #(< % pivot)]
         (recur (list*
                 (filter smaller? xs)
                 pivot
                 (remove smaller? xs)
                 parts)))
       (when-let [[x & parts] parts]
         (cons x (sort-parts parts)))))))

(defn qsort [xs]
    (sort-parts (list xs)))
```

Works really well...

```
(time (take 10 (qsort (shuffle (range 10000000)))))
"Elapsed time: 551.714003 msecs"
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Great! But...

However much I try I can't seem to work out how to apply this to a sequence of hashmaps.

I need something like:

```
(take 20 (qsort-by :created population))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need the top N elements a full sort is too expensive (even a lazy sort as the one in the JoC: it needs to keep nearly the all data set in memory).

You only need to scan (`reduce`) the dataset and keep the best N items so far.

```
=> (defn top-by [n k coll]
     (reduce
      (fn [top x]
        (let [top (conj top x)]
          (if (> (count top) n)
            (disj top (first top))
            top)))
      (sorted-set-by #(< (k %1) (k %2))) coll))
#'user/top-by
=> (top-by 3 first [[1 2] [10 2] [9 3] [4 2] [5 6]])
#{[5 6] [9 3] [10 2]}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!